# How to create django backend for alexa account linking

Tags: django, alexa-skills-kit, django-oauth-toolkit, alexa-smart-home-skill, alexa-account-linking

I want to know how can i use django auth toolkit for alexa accountg linking. I have completed from my side but when backend authrize user and send requeust to alexa redirect uri It,s throing error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s5mk.png)

I tried with creating application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As starting point, I would strongly recommend reading over the following blog and knowledge base articles. They cover the most common points of friction that Alexa developers encounter with account linking, as well as providing some tips on how to best debug your skill's account linking implementation:

App-to-App account linking debugging: https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/240817/app-to-app-account-linking-debugging-tips.html
Troubleshooting account linking blog: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2020/12/troubleshooting-common-account-linking-issues-with-alexa-skills
Account linking debugging knowledge base article: https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html

If after following those debugging steps you are still running into trouble,
we would need more information about this issue in order to help, would you mind  please open a case through our contact us page: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/contact-us

Please provide some more information:

1. Information about your issue
2. Exact time and date (in UTC, or with time zone) you tried and failed
3. Account linking test credentials